# Changing <li> text without changing html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text inside the `<li>` tag. I've looked at several places and all of them only have the `<li>` tag with some text. Mines has the `<a>` tag inside it. I have made slight modifications from the W3Schools site: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_active

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
       <li id="home"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li id="news"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li id="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to change the text "Home" to something else like "Hello" with pure JavaScript (no jQuery). When I use `innerHTML`, the `<a>` tag gets disrupted.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.children` to get the child element, so you can do something like:

```
document.getElementById("home").children[0].innerHTML = "Hello";
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted when you get the chance so it'll help out future visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the inner HTML of the `<a>` tag instead of the `<li>` tag, you can set the ID on the `<a>` as follows: `<a id="home-link" class="active" href="#home">` and then in JavaScript write `document.getElementById('home-link').innerHTML = "Hello";`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to disrupt the `<a>` tag by using `element.insertAdjacent
HTML(position, text)`.

So, for instance, `element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Woot!')` appends and `element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 'Woot!')` prepends "Woot!" to the chosen element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

You might even be able to avoid JS altogether, using CSS pseudo-elements.

Example: `li > a::before { content: "Woot!"; }` and `li > a::after { content: "Woot!"; }` would basically have the same effect as the JS examples above since, either way (JS or CSS), they would need to be positioned via CSS.